# How to auto-run maven project with Azure after CD and display correct webpage

Tags: java, azure, maven

I’m trying to host a webpage but I’m unsure as to how and googling doesn’t show anything relevant to what I’m trying to do specifically.

I have a Java maven project on GitHub, and I’ve set up CD to Azure so whenever I push to GitHub, Azure downloads the project.

When you run the maven program a “webpage.html” is created in the repository. I want this html file to be displayed when I enter my Azure webpage.

So, whenever I push to GitHub and Azure clones the project, I want it to run the maven program (to create the html file) and then display the html file when you enter the website. How do I do this?

I have verified that azure does indeed clone the git repository, but I don't see how I make it run the java code and display the html file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that “webpage.html” is in the “settings - configuration - default documents" list.

[image]